# Setting a variable equal to multiple names

Tags: javascript, html

so I'm very new to Javascript ;I'm trying so hard to learn it but it's difficult for me especially because I'm coming from an OOP standpoint (C++/Java) . Anyway ,I'm building a calculator and my question is I'm trying to set a single global variable to a long reference . Here's what i mean .

Here is what i have tried in order to make a single global variable to work instead of writing ( document.form.textview.value ) every single time.

```
1. var number = document.form.textview.value;

2. var number = newFunction();
    function newFunction() {
    return document.form.textview.value;
    }


3. i also tried using document.getelementbyID and queryselector but none of them worked.
```

what i have and is working :-

```
function insert(num) { // inserts a number into the textbox or form
    document.form.textview.value = document.form.textview.value + num;
}

function equal() { // calculates numbers
    var exp = document.form.textview.value;
    if (exp) {
        document.form.textview.value = eval(exp);
    }
}

function Squareroot() {
    document.form.textview.value = 
    eval(Math.sqrt(document.form.textview.value));
}
```

as you can see i have to write 'document.form.textview.value' every single time in order to get it to work instead i want a single global variable to do that for me.

This is what i want  :-

```
var number = document.form.textview.value;

function insert(num) {
    return number+num;
}

function equal() {
    if (number) {
       eval(number);
    }
}

function Squareroot() {
    eval(Math.sqrt(number));
}
```

html :-

```
 <form name="form">
        <input class="textview" name="textview">
        <table>
            <caption>
                <h1>↻</h1>
            </caption>
            <tr>
                <td onclick="Clearview()">C</td>
                <td>←</td>
                <td onclick="Takepercentage('')">%</td>
                <td onclick="insert('/')">/</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td onclick="insert('.')">.</td>
                <td onclick="exponents()">x<sup>2</sup></td>
                <td onclick="Squareroot()">√</td>
                <td onclick="insert('*')">*</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td onclick="insert(6)">6</td>
                <td onclick="insert(7)">7</td>
                <td onclick="insert(8)">8</td>
                <td onclick="insert('-')">-</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td onclick="insert(3)">3</td>
                <td onclick="insert(4)">4</td>
                <td onclick="insert(5)">5</td>
                <td onclick="insert('+')">+</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td onclick="insert(0)">0</td>
                <td onclick="insert(1)">1</td>
                <td onclick="insert(2)">2</td>
                <td onclick="equal()">=</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: create a function `const getValue = () => document.form.textview.value` then call it when you need the value `getValue()`

Comment: You can simply bind the input to a variable. Any time user changes the input update the variable. Probably would wanna use the `onkeyup` listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DOM is very much like any other OOP system you might be familiar with.  You can very easily make a reference to `document.form.textview`, acting as an object you can change by accessing or mutating its `value` property.  But if you create a reference to that property, getting or setting it simply changes the reference, and not the underlying object.

Think of it as similar to

```js
var r = new Rectangle(5, 3);
r.area() //=> 15
r.width  //=> 5
r.width + 7 //=> 12, but doesn't change the rectangle.
```

So by using `number.value` where you were hoping to use `number`, and setting `number` to `document.form.textview`, you should be able to get things to work:

```js
const number = document.form.textview;

function insert(num) {
    return number.value += '' + num;
}

function equal() {
    if (number.value) {
       eval (`number.value = ${number.value}`);
    }
}

function Squareroot() {
    number.value = Math.sqrt(number.value);
}
```

```html
<form name="form">
        <input class="textview" name="textview">
        <table>
            <caption>
                <h1>↻</h1>
            </caption>
            <tr>
                <td onclick="Clearview()">C</td>
                <td>←</td>
                <td onclick="Takepercentage('')">%</td>
                <td onclick="insert('/')">/</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td onclick="insert('.')">.</td>
                <td onclick="exponents()">x<sup>2</sup></td>
                <td onclick="Squareroot()">√</td>
                <td onclick="insert('*')">*</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td onclick="insert(6)">6</td>
                <td onclick="insert(7)">7</td>
                <td onclick="insert(8)">8</td>
                <td onclick="insert('-')">-</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td onclick="insert(3)">3</td>
                <td onclick="insert(4)">4</td>
                <td onclick="insert(5)">5</td>
                <td onclick="insert('+')">+</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td onclick="insert(0)">0</td>
                <td onclick="insert(1)">1</td>
                <td onclick="insert(2)">2</td>
                <td onclick="equal()">=</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much ; my question is i see you put eval (`number.value = ${number.value}` ) ?? what does that mean why couldn't i just use eval(number.value) . Correct me if im wrong isn't the $ sign part of jQuery ? can you explain that line

Comment: @Thatdude22: That's part of the syntax of [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals): inside backtick-delimited strings, you can embed expressions to be interpreted between `${` and `}`.  So, if the `value ` of  `number` is `5 + 7`, then this turns into something like `eval("number.value = 5 + 7")`.  The `$` character is how jQuery exposes its API, but it's just a legal  character allowed in any variable name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onkeyup` event listener to update the global variable. That way any time you want to reference `globalVal` you'll have the right value. This is also called **one way binding**. That is, any time you change the input value, the global variable will get updated, but not the other way around. In **two way binding**, a change made to the global variable or the input would result in both of them being updated.

```js
var globalVal = "";
function update(val) {
  globalVal = val;
  console.log(globalVal);
}
```

```html
<input id="textview" onkeyup="update(this.value)" class="textview" name="textview">
```